# ubuntu + gunicorn 30 секунд timeout

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

Стоит django на сервере ubuntu и gunicorn.
периодически при загрузке страницы она падает в таймаут на 30 секунд. в логах gunicorn видно, что это стандартная велична `timeout: 30`. как понять в чем проблема, чтобы сайт периодически не падал в эту паузу?

**/var/log/gunicorn/error.log**

```
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63901] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
  wsgi_app: None
  bind: ['unix:/run/ServiceCRM3.sock']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 5
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 30
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  print_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /home/lapitsky/crm3/CRM3
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 0
  group: 0
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: /var/log/gunicorn/access.log
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: /var/log/gunicorn/error.log
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: True
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags:
  statsd_prefix:
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: ServiceCRM3.wsgi:application
  pythonpath: None
paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f726f24e8b0>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f726f24e9d0>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f726f24eaf0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f726f24ec10>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f726f24ed30>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f726f24ee50>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f726f24ef70>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f726f2620d0>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f726f2621f0>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f726f262310>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f726f2623a0>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f726f2624c0>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f726f2625e0>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f726f262700>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f726f262820>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
strip_header_spaces: False
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63901] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63901] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63901] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/ServiceCRM3.sock (63901)
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63901] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63924] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63924
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63926] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63926
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63927] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63927
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63928] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63928
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63929] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63929
[2022-07-01 23:36:01 +0000] [63901] [DEBUG] 5 workers
```

Comment: Так это не пауза...у вас какой то запрос к сайту выполняется дольше чем 30 секунд. Вам не конфигурацию гуникорна смотреть нужно, а в чём проблема в вашем web-приложении. Вы должны выявить при каком конкретно запросе возникает такое длительное ожидание и какие данные передаются в этом запросе. Затем внести правки в обработчик этого запроса. Нужен дебаг. Для этого можете настроить логирование, просматривать запросы в консоле, воспользоваться инспектором браузера. Конечно же вы еще можете попытаться просто увеличить макс время ожидания в гуникорне, если это сработает и вас это устроит конечно...

Comment: это точно серверная ошибка, на локалке таких проблем нет

Comment: если у Вас эта ошибка возникает только при загрузке определенной страницы, значит проблема, вероятно, в вашем приложении. Я все же рекомендую Вам начать с отладки обработчика запроса, там уже можно будет определить что именно занимает столько времени. При деплое на сервер доступ к данным может быть дольше. В любом случае, данных, предоставленных Вами, точно не достаточно для однозначного определения проблемы. Тут нужно подключаться и смотреть, я лишь могу дать рекомендации, что я собственно и сделал. Я бы выставил принты/логи в обработчике для начала(уже на сервере, а не на локалке конечно).

Comment: нет, это ошибка при загрузке разных страниц и самое удивительное, что таймаут идет ровно 30 секунд

Comment: Думаю, вам нужно смотреть в сторону кол-ва свободной оперативной памяти, раз на локалке все работает...

Comment: @JopaBoga в том что таймаут ровно 30 секунд идёт нет ничего удивительного, это максимальное время ожидание установленное в gunicorn, как я сказал, вы можете попробовать просто изменить эту настройку, увиличив максимальное время ответа от сервера и возможно решить таким образом проблему.  У вас же написанно timeout: 30 в настройках, так чему вы удивляетесь? Серевер не успевает по какой то причине за 30 секунд обработать ваш запрос, а больше ему ждать вы не разрешаете. Конечно это не лучшее решение, но возможно с таймаутом, скажем, в 120, хотя бы падать не будет.

Comment: @paqstd нет, памяти очень много, 64гб на сервере

Comment: @Spartak почему на локалке тогда нет такой проблемы? на сервере тот же код, и сервер мощнее локалки в разы

Comment: @JopaBoja, гуникорн запускает несколько корутин, я бы убедился, что их количесттво у вас равно количеству ядер +1 и что все корутины работают корректно. попытался бы выявить на какой именно корутине у вас ошибка возникает. так как у вас это происходит на различных вьюшках время от времени, то, возможно, проблема возникает на определенной корутине. Если таймаут всегда при определенной корутине, то с ней явно что то не так и надо, хотябы, рестартнуть ёё. Можете передеплоить всё с 0 по этому гайду. https://hostgeek.ru/manuals/50-deploj-django-gunicorn-nginx-supervisor.html , всегда им пользуюсь.

Comment: @JopaBoja возможно некоторые горутины упали, но сервер всё-равно пытается обработать запрос через них.